# Referencing hash item inside itself

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

I've got a pretty short question. Is it possible to initialize a hash with something like this:

```
row = {
    :title => "row title",
    :slug => row[:title].paremeterize
}
```

In other words, could I somehow reference an unitialized hash inside itself or I have to do it this way:

```
row = {
    :title => "row title"
}
row[:slug] = row[:title].paremeterize
```

Thanks for the comments. Of course, this code won't work. I asked if there is a similar way, maybe with a different syntax. Ruby has been full of surprises for me :)

Comment: This seems like a simple, "Have you tried it, and if so what happens?" question. Not to sound snarky, but what is there for us to do except try it, and tell you if it succeeds or fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going about this in a rather strange way. Try to think about what you are doing when you run into cases where you are trying to use the language in ways that are rarely documented (or impossible).

```
title = "foobar"

row = {
  :title => title,
  :slug => title.parameterize
}
```

Even better…

```
class Row
  attr_accessor :title

  def slug; title.parameterize; end
end

foo = Row.new :title => 'foo bar'
foo.slug    #=> "foo-bar"
```

Comment: +1 for the class approach. Maybe you meant "class Row < OpenStruct"?

Comment: There are too many good ways to do this. I went with the fundamentals, but a class inheriting from a struct is probably a good option if each row is merely structured data.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following in IRB,

```
row = {
    :title => "row title",
    :slug => row[:title]
}
```

you get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. So no you can't do that, given that `row` hasn't been fully initialized at that point and is a `nil` object.